# Google form inserts sheet row in unexpected location

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I am having a strange issue regarding in which row of a linked sheet a google form places a new form row.  Normally, each form submit adds a row to the sheet, starting with row 2 (row 1 is the header), as expected.  If I delete all the rows in the sheet, form submits restart at row 2, as expected.  But, now suppose I manually populate say the first 10 rows of the form (again, leaving row 1 as the header, so rows 2-11).  Now when I do a form submit, I would expect row 12 to be added to and so on but instead, form starts at row 2 and wipes out my pre-populated row data.  It seems that the form and the sheet have an internal "next row number" that is not based on the actual contents of the sheet.  Can anyone shed any light one this?

Comment: Can you share the related code for us to see where exactly the fault might lie?

Comment: Not easily.  Clear all rows in the form except header row 1. Manually add 100 rows to a sheet bound to a form (after the header row), run an app script on the sheet: lastrow = sheet.getLastRow() and you'll get back 102, as expected.  Now run a form and it will overwrite row 2 (incorrect)  (not the header row) rather than adding the row at 103, as expected.  Somehow the form/sheet interaction keeps a "magic" hidden row number that does not sync with the actual number of rows in the sheet.

Answer (score 3):

I run into same problem. And found solution (after 2 hours of digging, where is the problem)

You need to use a function 
`sheet.insertRowsBefore(rowIndex, numberOfRowsToBeInserted)` 
first to create new rows (space) for your data and AFTER add your data to those created rows. 
You can add new rows manually in google sheets of course - it works the same.

Explanation: There is an internal form property which holds a row index where a new form submissions will goes after a form submit.

When you only fill data, the index for new form submissions stays at previous position, so it rewrites your (any) data in cells.

Expect similar behavior when deleting a row data - if you delete only values (by delete key for. eg), then there will stay empty row when new form submission appears. Again you need to use function sheet.deleteRow(index) to delete data and change index of new row for new submissions.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are using the `getActiveCell()` or `getActiveRange()` method to find the last row. Whereas, you should be using `getDataRange()` method to get the last row and columns. `getActiveCell()` or `getActiveRange()` methods point to the location of the cursor on the Spreadsheet. Hence, if at the time it was at Row 1 - Col2, that's where it'll insert your info. Refer to this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getActiveCell%28%29) for more information.

Comment: Nope, if I have 10 rows in the SS, I am seeing 10 returned (as expected).  Cursors are meaningless in this context since there are no "users" editing. This is not the issue - the issue is why does google forms INSERT rows above the rows that are there already there as opposed to AFTER the ones that are there.

Comment: well, in that case.. without the code... we are all shooting arrows in the dark as it's hard to tell what might be going wrong. Sorry about that.

Comment: Forget code.  Do this:

1) Open this form: http://goo.gl/forms/jj1KcvaSc4
2) Submit an entry
3) Open this sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_Qd4Ep4bkurjzHfSA_dTg9EcNinU3F4-kA5MciK7yyE/edit?usp=sharing
4) Note that the row you just added was ABOVE the other rows that have 1...4 in col B

Why is that?  I would expect the new form rows to be added at the end of the existing rows.

Comment: Oh. now I understand what you mean. I have seen this behaviour before. It occurs for no apparent reason. Or at least not one that I know. You'll have better chances of finding an answer, [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list). Report this as an issue.

Comment: I know this an old topic but to fix a situation like this I grabbed the Row for the latest result and dragged it to where I wanted. After that, new data came into the sheet at the right spot.

Answer (score 0):

This happens by design so that form submissions never overwrite user inserted data. This is well demonstrated in this response[1].

I believe you could resolve problems if you create a script to insert your older data using the `createResponse()` method[2].

[1] https://support.google.com/docs/thread/10244473/google-forms-inserting-at-top-of-sheet?hl=en

[2] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#createResponse()